# Spring Data JPA Use SpEL syntax to conditionally build query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

I tried to build a query depending on a boolean @Param, and the difficulty is that I build the end of the query without using a classical operator ( = , <, > ...).

For the example, let's assume I want to fetch all my Sales objects that are not related to an Account object (if I pass false in @Param) or that are related to an Account (if I pass true in the @Param) :

```
@Query("SELECT sale .... 
 WHERE sale.account :#{isbound ? NOT NULL : IS NULL}")
public List<Sale> getSales(@Param("isbound") boolean isBound);
```

I tried a few syntaxs based on the official Spring documentation (https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions), but all their examples are working with an operator before the expression, like this:  entity = #{the_expression}.

Does somebody once tried this and can give me the good way to write this ? thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor your query code like bellow:

```
@Query("SELECT sale .... 
        WHERE (true = :isbound and sale.account is not null)
          or (false = :isbound and sale.account is null)")
public List<Sale> getSales(@Param("isbound") boolean isBound);
```

Comment: Alright !! that's a good workaround, yesterday my brain was stuck on the SpEL syntax, thx !